# Vim specific mkview and loadview in order to avoid issues

Tags: vim

I have the following in my `~/.vimrc` , which was working fine for saving folds and view information. Then, I removed the 'auto-pairs' plugin and vim started crashing, apparently, previously saved views were calling functions that have now been removed. How can I preserve a buffer's foldings and marks for example without saving its key mappings?

```
augroup autosave_buffer
 autocmd!
 autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
 autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
augroup END
```

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to delete existing views before trying to remove values from `:help viewoptions`.

Comment: I commented out these lines and everything loaded just fine... I can rebuild my folds as the files I opened are pretty small but I'm inquiring to see how to deal with future uninstalls as this can get problematic :-)

Comment: What is saved by `:mkview` is dictated by the `'viewoptions'` option in my previous comment. Read the relevant help section and play with the available values.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! :-) I'll take a look and pick and choose :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably configure

```
:set viewoptions-=options
```

(Same recommendation for `'sessionoptions'`.) As long as you don't define mappings on-the-fly, this isn't necessary, and it causes the problems you've described with capturing plugin mappings (that would get redefined by the plugin, anyway).

Comment: Perfect :-) This seems to fix the issue. I have to comment out this line first `autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview` in order for `mkview` to overwrite the buffer next time I close the window. Your answer will help avoid this in the future =) Thank you very much!